# Can't turn header image into link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, header

I'm trying to turn my header at http://ukgraffiti.tumblr.com/ into a link back to the main page.

CSS:

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 50px 500px 90px 80px;
  background-image: url(http://s32.postimg.org/nqrhk4r9h/graffiti_header3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <h1><a href="http://ukgraffiti.tumblr.com/">{Title}</a></h1>
</div>
```

The problem seems to be that the id and h1 actually control the default text header, which I've hidden with CSS, rather than the image I've put in its place.

I tried giving creating a simple link with a different id, and then changed the id in the CSS, but this didn't work and messed up my layout anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about <a><h1></h1></a> flipping h1 and a tags?

Comment: Thanks, but not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: `<a href="http://ukgraffiti.tumblr.com/"><h1>{Title}</h1></a>`

Comment: @Tin Sorry, Tin, it didn't work. Header image still not a link and it made the default header title visible. It also shifted my search box slightly.

Comment: I added an answer. Let me know if it helps at all.

Comment: I test my answer direct on your site with chrome. I change html and set the css. So it should work directly. Let me know if you have issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can just apply the header id to the `<a>` tag:

```
<a id="header" href="http://ukgraffiti.tumblr.com/">{Title}</a>
```

Comment: Fraid not, David. This didn't turn my header into a link and it also messed up my layout.

Comment: Okay, that did turn my header image into a link, but it threw my search box out of line, and it also made the default text header visible.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at your site now. The issue is that div is what you wanna make clickable because it has a background image. So do this

Edited: So I made some changes to get what you may want

```
<div>
    <a href="http://ukgraffiti.tumblr.com/"><img src="http://s32.postimg.org/nqrhk4r9h/graffiti_header3.jpg"></a>
    <div id="topsearch">
    <form action="http://ukgraffiti.tumblr.com/search" method="get" id="searchform">
        <p><input onfocus="this.value=&#39;&#39;" type="text" value="Search" name="q" results="5"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Also to remove white gap, remove `margin-top: 200px;` from #content.

Comment: Thanks very much. This almost works. It turns the header into a link, but now I can't use the search box, because clicking in the search box activates the link back to the home page. All I did here was add the first a href line in your code above the div id header. I'm not really sure if I'm supposed to do anything with all the commented out area.

Comment: You can remove the commented area. And add "search" section where you want it. But I'd not put "search" section in the div header.

Comment: I don't think I can do what I want. If I move the search box code out of the header div, it disappears altogether. Am I right in thinking I can't have the search box sat on top of the image which is a link?

Comment: If I hover over the top of 'G' in 'Graffiti', the cursor turns to a finger because it's picking up the original header title which I've hidden with CSS. Can I somehow make this area bigger so that it covers the area of the header image?

Comment: I'm probably doing it wrong, but I tried adding your edited code and it just threw everything out of flunter. I think it's probably easier to just leave it as it was.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your html:

```
<div id="header">
  <h1><a href="http://ukgraffiti.tumblr.com/">UK GRAFFITI</a></h1>
  <p id="description"><br></p>
  <div id="topsearch">
    <form action="/search" method="get" id="searchform">
      <p>
        <input onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" value="Search" name="q" results="5">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this one:

```
<a id="header" href="href="http://ukgraffiti.tumblr.com/">
    <h1 class="header-text">UK GRAFFITI</h1>
</a>
<form action="/search" method="get" id="searchform">
    <input onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" value="Search" name="q" results="5">
</form>
```

And add this to your css:

```
#searchform {
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 128px;
  left: 738px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Here you can set the position of your search box.

And set the text-indent for the headline. Think you have it as text just for search engines.

```
.header-text {
  text-indent: -9999em;
}
```

@Jud This work. I make a full copy of your page html and change like described. Here you can test it.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jannahody/pen/EKeMWy)

Comment: Replace it with what?

Comment: With the second source block. I update the post, so may you need to reload this page.

Comment: Sorry, Jan. That didn't work either. I think the problem is that I'm trying to overlay a search box on top of a clickable header image.

Comment: This still doesn't work I'm afraid. When you click in the search box it activates the header link. Try it on your PEN and you will see. Thanks very much for all your efforts, though.

Comment: Ok fix it. Please test.